# Sun T5440: Weblogic start take too long

Tags: weblogic, sun, weblogic-10.x

We are using weblogic 10.1 on T5440 servers but the start time takes too long as compared with V890 servers.

But after start the cpu performance is excellent.

For example weblogic server start takes 15-20 min. on a v890 server bu the same weblogic server starts in ~50 min on  T5440.

Did you face the same problem? Or do you have any idea to shorten the time of start.

Comment: Maybe more success on serverfault.com

Comment: Can you provide more details about the differences between the machines (e.g. CPUs, RAM). Are you using the same JVM and same JVM settings? PS: 20mn is quite long though. What kind of application is it, how many EJBs?

Answer (score 1):

Kadir, 
According to the Sun guys this is somewhat expected. T series multi thread architecture is designed to perform better for throughput. But at the initialization phase single thread code  takes place.
I think you have tried this but please try the other options as a last shot:

http://www.itonguard.com/20090313/weblogic-starts-slow